# How to work with Selenium WebDriver on Mac OS?

Tags: python, macos, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm currently trying to learn how to automate things with Python (3.7).

So first I've installed the Selenium Standalone Server 3.141.5 with Homebrew on my MacBook (Mojave 10.14.1). I thought this would be an easy way and the installation was successful. After this I took a small Python script to test the Firefox webDriver with Selenium - just to see if everything works fine, but no...

Eclipse just gives me this Error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "/Users/Sandra/Documents/eclipse-workspace/Automatisierung/Test_Package/Firefox_webDriver_Test.py",
>   line 11, in 
>       from selenium import webdriver ImportError: No module named selenium

Before running the script I've started Selenium in the Terminal with: `selenium-server -port 4444`

This is the script code (I can also use Chrome or Safari instead of Firefox):

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

browser = webdriver.Firefox()

browser.get('https://www.ebay.de')
assert 'eBay.de' in browser.title

elem = browser.find_element_by_name('p')  # Find the search box
elem.send_keys('seleniumhq' + Keys.RETURN)

browser.quit()
```

Comment: Why did you download the server? why not just download the module?

Comment: You need to download the module, the server isn't the package that can be used as an import. `pip install -U selenium`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting this error:

> from selenium import webdriver ImportError: No module named selenium

Because python cannot find the selenium module. All that is installed is the server

The easiest way to use selenium is to download the non-server version of the software which on the selenium download page is one of the links below that in the *"Selenium Client & WebDriver Language Bindings"* section. (I have no clue how to access the module if you are using the server)

The only reason why you would want to use the server version is stated on the website:

*"The Selenium Server is needed in order to run Remote Selenium WebDriver. Selenium 3.X is no longer capable of running Selenium RC directly, rather it does it through emulation and the WebDriverBackedSelenium interface."*

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but it still doesn't work like I want it. I tried to get the Selenium Client & WebDriver for Python. I wasn't sure if I have pip on my system, but the installation page says that python 3>=3.4 has it already ... so okay. I tried to run pip install -U selenium but only got this back: Sandras-MacBook-Pro:~ Sandra$ pip install -U selenium
-bash: pip: command not found

Comment: @Lejonet.98 pip should be automatically included when you install python 3+, if pip doesn't work you will have to download the wheel manually and install it manually. Type `pip --version` into the terminal, and type `python --version` into the terminal to check pip and python versions

Comment: I think I found one point why it's not working. When I enter python --version it says I have Python 2.7.10, but yesterday I installed a new version 3.7.1. How can I change to the new one?

Comment: Sandras-MacBook-Pro:~ Sandra$ python --version
Python 2.7.10
Sandras-MacBook-Pro:~ Sandra$ which python
/usr/bin/python
Sandras-MacBook-Pro:~ Sandra$ which python3.7
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/bin/python3.7
Sandras-MacBook-Pro:~ Sandra$

Comment: @Lejonet.98 the python3 path might not be in your environment, there is a way to have multiple versions of python on your computer, but first try `python3 --version` and `pip3 --version`

Comment: @Lejonet.98 Also, I might not be the best person to help you with this problem. I don't have much experience with this problem so my answer would be to uninstall python 3.7 then reinstall python 3.7 and make sure you have the **Add python 3.7 to PATH** checked, then if that doesn't work uninstall both python versions then reinstall python 3.7